# Is A Photon A Wave Or Does It Emit/Create A Wave?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, wave-particle-duality

In my search for more clarification about photons being a wave or particle, I found a response here [Photon's create waves](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_photon_will_decide_when_to_behave_like_a_wave_or_particle) that said that photons don't become a wave but rather create a wave. This contradicts a lot that I have looked up that say that photons either act as a wave or particle. Is that just the simplified version or was the response in the hyperlink wrong? Please simplify your responses as much as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Photons do not create or emit waves.

Comment: Photon is not a wave as for the term would not even had been necessary. Beside technical treatment that I don't know well, it is while interacting that it manifests itself.

Answer (score 0):

Photons are quantized excitations of the electromagnetic field. A field in the n-th mode “contains” n photons, which means the vacuum has been excited n times

Answer (score -1):

Photons don't exist and there is no "speed of light". Light is a coaxial circuit, field perturbation. A transverse vibration. The "speed of light" is the rate of induction through a medium. IE, the Ether. Ask Tesla, who basically invented the modern world, or ask Einstein, who invented nothing. All we see are the "attributes" of light, not light itself. Light only manifests itself when it meets resistance. Hence, it is a coaxial circuit.

Comment: I don't understand your arguments and I don't believe that this is answering the question. The question is not about the philosophical idea of existence.